# Clipping classified image by shapefile in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have classified an image tile, but I cannot clip it along the area shape.
How do I do it and get my study area classified and clipped in a TIFF file?

Comment: Welcome Sajneen. As a new user, please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about our focused Q&A format. Please add what you've tried already and where you're getting stuck, along with the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create clipping function
var clipper = function(image){
  return image.clip(geometry); // Add the table or shapefile here
};

// Load asset (not necessary) ie. region you would like to clip your data over

var classClipped = classified.map(clipper);
Map.addLayer(classClipped, {}, 'clipped image');
```

Answer (score 0):

First load your shapefile in asset tab
then:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/my_user/my_shapefile");

var Temp1 = ee.ImageCollection ('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate ('2017-01-01' ,'2017-12-30')
.filterMetadata ('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'Less_Than', 20);
     
var Temp1b = Temp1.reduce(ee.Reducer.median()); // until this line is an example to get an image from a catalogue
// Then get that image clipped by the shapefile:
var my_clip = Temp1b.clip(table);
```